# Google Script function is not returning the correct local formatted date

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timezone

column A contains dates (UTC formatted) that I wish to format to a particular timezone, although the function is not returning the correct local formatted date.

```
function LOCALTIME(datetimeString) {
  var originalDate = new Date(datetimeString);
  return Utilities.formatDate(originalDate, "Australia/Adelaide", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, when `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` is modified to `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss`, what result will you get? [Ref1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) And, also "Australia/Adelaide" might be `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone()`. [Ref2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getspreadsheettimezone)

Comment: Also, this thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/28956532/7108653

Comment: your suggestion has addressed the formatting issue, but it hasn't converted the time to "Australia/Adelaide" even when updating to `...getSpreadsheetTimeZone()`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. When `Australia/Adelaide` is modified to `UTC+09:30`, what result will you get?

Comment: This `2020-05-20T01:46:00.929Z` converted to `2020-05-19 16:16:01`, should have been `2020-05-20 10:16:01` that is approx 19 hours behind. It's currently not being converted to the correct timezone of Australia/Adelaide for some reason

Comment: Thank you for replying. `Australia/Adelaide` is `UTC+09:30`. But I thought that in order to achieve your conversion, it is required be `UTC+08:30`. How about this? If I misunderstood your goal, please tell me.

Comment: using `GMT_08:30` still does not convert to Australia/Adelaide correctly. The requirement is simple, convert date in col A to Australia/Adelaide timezone

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm my understanding for your goal. You want to convert from `2020-05-20T01:46:00.929Z` to `2020-05-20 10:16:01`. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is not correct, it is required to change the direction of my thinking.

Comment: yes correct! when a new date (`2020-05-20T01:46:00.929Z`) was added the local time was `2020-05-20 11:16:01` (note correction on hour), but the script converts it `2020-05-20 01:46:00` when using Australia/Adelaide as the timezone

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, the conversion of `UTC+08:30` is required. So for example, when it's `var originalDate = new Date("2020-05-20T01:46:00.929Z");`, how about using `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(originalDate.getTime() + (60 * 60 * 8.5 * 1000)), "Etc/GMT", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")`? In this script, `2020-05-20T01:46:00.929Z` is converted with `UTC+08:30`. The result of `2020/05/20 10:16:00` is obtained. If this was not the direction you expect, I have to apologize.

Comment: this is not working with your suggestion, it outputs the same date but formatted to `2020-05-20 01:46:01` - perhaps we should move the discussion to chat?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I my environment, when I used above script, `2020-05-20T01:46:00.929Z` becomes `2020/05/20 10:16:00`. So unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So when I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of the solution. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: hm really?! how are you using the function? I use in the cell `=LOCALTIME(TEXT(A2, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))`

Comment: I worked it out, the issue was on the way the formula was being used, it needs to be used as such `=LOCALTIME(TO_TEXT(A2))` the date was not being passed as a String - thanks so much for your help

Comment: You should write an answer to your question and accept it so others know it's answered.