# How does Utilities.formatDate return an array index?

Tags: javascript, date-format, google-ads-script

I saw this code:

```
var DAYS = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday',
            'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

  var pastQuery = 'SELECT ' + fields +
      ' FROM ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT WHERE DayOfWeek=' +
      DAYS[getDateStringInTimeZone('u', new Date())].toUpperCase() +
      ' DURING ' + dateRangeToStart + ',' + dateRangeToEnd;
```

How does `getDateStringInTimeZone('u', new Date())` returns an index for `DAYS` array?

```
function getDateStringInTimeZone(format, date, timeZone) {
  date = date || new Date();
  timeZone = timeZone || AdsApp.currentAccount().getTimeZone();
  return Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format);
}
```

I thought `Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)` returns a string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956532/google-apps-script-date-format-issue-utilities-formatdate

Comment: do you need to cast your string to a number? - u Day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday) Number 1

Comment: It's a code I'm reading. I assumed it should return an int index. Otherwise how would it be used with the `DAYS` array?

Comment: the function itself returns a string, so i would presume you would need to parseInt before trying to use it as an array index