# Converting Sheets date format via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a google spreadsheet in which I need to check if the value entered in the cell by the user is a date, if it is a date, it must be formatted as `dd/MM/yy`, if it is not a date, than the value must be converted to uppercase.

The date conversion is what is not working by now, and i would like some help on how can i do that.

This is how the script is right now. Thanks in advance.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var tab = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  if (tab != "backup")  { //this is NOT working
    if(isDate(e.range.getValue())) {
      var date = new Date(e.range.getValue());
      var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT-3", 'dd/MM/yy');
      e.range.setValue(formattedDate);
    } else { //this is working
        e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase()); 
      }
  }
}

function isDate(date) {
  return(Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]');
}
```

**EDIT:** the simplest solution i found for this is:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var tab = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  if (tab != "backup")  { 
    if(isDate(e.range.getValue())) {
      e.range.setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    } else { 
        e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase()); 
      }
  }
}

function isDate(date) {
  return(Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]');
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `The date conversion is what is not working by now`? Because, in your script, I thought that when a date object is put into a cell except for "backup" sheet, the script works. First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Can you specify any error or elaborate how your date conversion isn't working?

Comment: i want to force all dates entered by user to be formatted as dd/MM/yy, regardless of the format in which the user typed. the way it is, it doesn't cause any errors, but it also doesn't make any changes to the date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not fully familiar with your data and/or error you are encountering but how about this **alternative solution**:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var tab = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();

  if (tab != "backup")  {
    if(isDate(e.range.getValue())) {
      var date = new Date(e.range.getValue());
      var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT-3", "''dd/MM/yy"); // using '' to force string literal
      e.range.setValue(formattedDate);
    } else { //this is working
        e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase()); 
      }
  }
}

function isDate(date) {
  return(Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]');
}
```

You can use this symbol `''` to force the format of date to your desired output.

**Result:**

[image]

Ref: [Google Apps Script date format issue (Utilities.formatDate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956532/google-apps-script-date-format-issue-utilities-formatdate)

Comment: Please let me know if you have questions. Hope this helps.